# How to make API Platform autodiscovery mechanism for Mercure hub work with Docker image?

Tags: docker, symfony, api-platform.com, mercure

I've developped a demo project to illustrate a presentation I'm doing about the [Mercure](https://mercure.rocks/) protocol, in which I also use API Platform. I had used the autodiscovery mechanism to retrieve the Mercure hub url (API Platform sends a `Link` header so that the front app can get the hub url without knowing it beforehand). But I had to make refactoring (the project was using docker images & composer repo from the company where I work, where I first presented Mercure) and at some point (I can't remember when exactly), the autodiscovery mechanism didn't work anymore.

I've found out why it didn't work, and that is because API Platform sends the Mercure hub url indicated in the `.env` file, which is not `http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure` (the hub url I subscribe to), but `http://mercure/.well-known/mercure`, where the first `mercure` is the name of my Mercure docker container. And my front app tried to subscribe to that url, which doesn't exist. To temporarily solve the problem, I've just hard-coded the hub url in my front app, but I would really like to know if there's a solution to use the autodiscovery mechanism with the Mercure docker image.

**The error I'm getting when `MERCURE_PUBLISH_URL` in `.env` = `http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure` :**
`Couldn't connect to server for "http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure".`

**My `.env` working configuration :**
`MERCURE_PUBLISH_URL=http://mercure/.well-known/mercure`
NB: I've tried setting `MERCURE_SUBSCRIBE_URL=http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure` but it didn't change a thing

**The bit of my front app where I subscribe to the hub :**
*The commented-out code is how to autodiscover the hub url by parsing the Link header, which I can do right now for the reasons explained above.*

```js
// const hubUrl = response.headers.link.match(/<([^>]+)>;\s+rel=(?:mercure|"[^"]*mercure[^"]*")/)[1];

const es = new EventSource(`http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure?topic=${document.location.origin}/api/pizzas/{id}`);
es.onmessage = ({data}) => {
    // doing something here
}
```

**My docker-compose Mercure configuration :**

```
    mercure:
        image: dunglas/mercure
        container_name: mercure
        environment:
            ALLOW_ANONYMOUS: 1
            JWT_KEY: aVerySecretKey
            PUBLISH_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: '*'
            CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: http://localhost
        ports:
            - 3000:80
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. You found solution?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I've never found one and managed without autodiscovery. 